# tensor product of algebras over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

> Let $k$ be a commutative field and $E,F$ two commutative, associative,
> unital $k$-algebras whose respective unit elements $e,e'$ are
> non-zero. Let $\eta_E:K\rightarrow E$ and $\eta_F:K\rightarrow F$ be
> the canonical ring homomorphisms such that $\eta_E(1)=e$ and
> $\eta_F(1)=e'$. These mappings are injective and allow us to identify
> $K$ with a subfield of $E$ (resp. $F$).
>
> Let $u:E\rightarrow E\otimes_KF$ and $v:F\rightarrow E\otimes_KF$ be
> the canonical homomorphisms such that $u(x)=x\otimes e'$ and
> $v(y)=e\otimes y$, for all $x\in E$ and $y\in F$. These mappings are
> injective and allow us to identify $E$ and $F$ with subalgebras of
> $E\otimes_KF$, both having as unit element the unit element $e\otimes
>  e'$.
>
> In $E\otimes_K F$, we have $E\cap F=K$.

Can someone please translate $E\cap F=K$ into expressions without identifications? I think $u(E)$ replaces $E$ and $v(F)$ replaces $F$.

What should replace $K$? Maybe $u(\eta_E(K))?$ But then let $z\in u(E)\cap v(F)$. Then $e\otimes y=z=x\otimes e'$ for some $x\in E$ and $y\in F$. How to show that this is in $u(\eta_E(K))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $K$, use
$$u(\eta_E(K))=v(\eta_F(K))=\{c\cdot e\otimes e':c\in K\}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you. If $x\otimes e'=e\otimes y$, how to show that $x\otimes e'\in u(\eta_E(K))$?

Comment: Do you know how to construct a basis of the tensor product given bases in the original vector spaces?

Comment: Yes, but the basis over $K$ or $\eta_E(K)$?

Comment: It's the same. Everything is over $K$ anyway.